# graphql regex filter keeps giving invalid escape sequence errors

Tags: reactjs, regex, graphql, escaping, gatsby

No matter what I try, like escaping `\w+` with `\\w+` or even `\\\\w+` I cannot get gatsby/graphql to understand my query. Or so it seems. Many times I can see the exact data I want rendered on the page EXACTLY how I'd like, but it's obscured by gatsby's error message overlay telling me that graphql is experiencing an invalid escape sequence around `\w`. Here is my code:

File structure:

```
site/
-src/
--content/
---adventures/
----example/
-----index.mdx
-----etc...
----doip/
-----index.mdx
-----etc...
----lomp/
-----index.mdx
-----etc...
```

Desired result:

I have three directories with `.mdx` sub-pages I would like to list on `/src/pages/adventures.js`. I want to grab only the indexes listed above. *There are many other directories with other `.mdx` files within each adventure directory* so any graphql query without some sort of filter provides dozens of results, when I only want the three. I want what should be `/adventures/\w+/$/i` but nothing works.

My query:

My query has taken MANY forms as I've tried to troubleshoot this, but as-is, this doesn't work. Neither does `"/adventures/\\\\w+/$/i"`, or "/adventures\/\w+\/$/i" or any variation I've tried or read about. My query as written on my `adventures.js` file started as:

```
query AdventuresListPageQuery {
    allMdx(filter: {fields: {slug: {regex: "/adventures\\\\/\\\\w+\\\\/$/i"}}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          frontmatter {
            title
            setting
            levels
            playernum
          }
          fields {
            slug
          }
          body
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Please help me craft a query that only grabs the files I need :(

Comment: Tried `regex: /adventures\/\w+\/$/i`? Without quotation marks.

Comment: Just tried it. Got this error: 
`GraphQLError: /Users/g/Sites/dmcm/src/pages/adventures.js: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character "/".`

Comment: If it has problems with regex literal, try a constructor: `regex: new RegExp('adventures/\\w+/$','i')` or `regex: new RegExp('adventures/[^/]+/$','i')`

Comment: That gives me `Syntax Error: Expected ":", found "(".`

Answer (score 1):

Changing my query filter to instead use `.+` instead of `\w+` seems to achieve my desired results. Seems like a less explicit solution than I'd like, and I'm not sure how extensible this solution will be as my site expands, but the labor of trying to figure out the *exact* way gatsby/graphql want `\w+` formatted is too irritating for the moment.

final query filter: `filter: {slug: {regex: "/adventures/.+/$/"}}`